# Use Wildcard (*) with RegEx in VBA to match anything

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to use Regex to match any character (This is just a piece of code from a larger project). I got the below to work, but seems like it is wrong, is there a proper way to search for any character via RegEx?

```
strPattern = "([!@#$%^&*()]?[a-z]?[0-9]?)"
```

Eg: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
Public Sub RegExSearch()
    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim rng As Range, rcell As Range
    Dim strInput As String, strPattern As String

    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1")

    With regexp 
    .Global = False 
    .MultiLine = False 
    .ignoreCase = True 
    .Pattern = strPattern 
    End With

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells

        strPattern = "([!@#$%^&*()]?[a-z]?[0-9]?)" ' This matches everything, but seems improper

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = rcell.Value

            If regexp.test(strInput) Then
                MsgBox rcell & " Matched in Cell" & rcell.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are willing to accept _any_ string input, then why bother using a regex at all?

Comment: Do you need to also match `newline`?

Comment: [/S/s]* matches everything

Comment: Fly by downvoter a year later with no comments? Please tell me what to improve in this question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `M` in `MCVE` stands for `minimal`. Hence, I removed the reason `why`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
. "Wildcard." The unescaped period matches any character, except a new line. 

strPattern = "."
```

Or as @RonRosenfeld pointed out, if you need to match everything INCLUDING a "new line" then this would work.

```
strPattern = "[/S/s]*"
```

https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/